# Can't load the Google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I followed step by step from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start. Built project with 'Generate Signed APK' and installed to phone, but i got only the grey background and small title "Google" in the left bottom angle.

So, how can i fix it?

Activity

```
package napc.gmaps;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
    }
}
```

activity_maps

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="napc.gmaps.MapsActivity" />
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="napc.gmaps">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Are you generating your SHA1 key from the release version or debug version of your apk - they will differ.

Comment: did you change your package name or something at google developer console?

Comment: issue is your generating android key from developer console, try to uninstall  app and install

Comment: I took the key from "google_maps_api.xml" file, which generate automate when i created project with standard map activity.
Need to get key from console? keytool e.t.c?
No, I have not changed package name

Comment: Go to the Developer's Console > Credentials > New Credentials > API Key > Android Key. You will need the package name and the SHA1 key then 'Create'. Paste the generated key to your `google_maps_api.xml`.

Comment: I did it, but, i think, with debug key. How i can get the release key? Didn't found any information about that.

Comment: Here is the reference [getting release certificate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en#release-cert), maybe the fingerprint you used is for the debug certificate.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Its working.